# in the decade between 20 and 30

Tags: grammatical-number

*In the decade between my 20 and 30 I used to listen to the psychedelic rock bands.*

Do you find this sentence OK? I would like to express as best as possible that when I was 20, 21, 22, …,30 I used to do a particular thing.

Comment: Bear in mind that *decades* are almost always "calendar-relative", and start with a year divisible by 10. You could feasibly refer to your ***third** decade* above, but it would normally be perceived as a somewhat facetious usage - particularly for such a *low* age. It's not quite so obviously facetious when referring to someone [*in his **ninth** decade*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in+his+ninth+decade%22), because we understand that the writer is trying to "big things up" (and *ninth decade* sounds more impressive than ***eighties***, purely because of how the numbers work).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This decade is called your *twenties.*

> In my twenties I used to listen to psychedelic rock bands.

> 1.1 (twenties) The numbers from twenty to twenty-nine, especially the years of a century or of a person’s life:
>   *he’s in his late twenties*
>   *cars built in the Twenties*
>
> [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/twenty)

The same applies to *teens, thirties, forties, fifties...*

Comment: As a footnote, we can also use the prefixes _mid-_, _early_, and _late_ with these words; e.g.: _In my early twenties, I listened to psychedelic rock bands; in my mid-thirties, I listened to folk rock, and now that I'm in my late forties, I listen to alternative punk._